# Blob conversion: Get file as xlsx

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, xlsx

I am trying to send an email that has a `xlsx` file attached but the problem I'm running into is that the file is opened as PDF when I download it

This is my code:

```
function sendMail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(['test value']);

  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = ss.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID); 
  var blob = file.getBlob();

  blob.setName("test.xlsx");

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'xxxxx@gmail.com',
    'Test',
    'test.',
    {
      attachments: blob
    }
  );
}
```

If I try to open the file directly from the email it says:
`Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes.

To learn more about the Google Docs editors, please visit our help center.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

### Modification points :

- When Spreadsheet is converted to blob using `DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).getBlob()`, the Spreadsheet is automatically converted to PDF.

  - It is required to convert from Spreadsheet to xlsx file.
- When it attaches blob to e-mail, please use `attachments: [blob]`.

The modified script which reflected above is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function sendMail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(['test value']);

  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = ss.getId();

  // Added
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/export?format=xlsx";
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
  };
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName("test.xlsx");
  // Added

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'xxxxx@gmail.com',
    'Test',
    'test.',
    {
      attachments: [blob] // Modified
    }
  );
}
```

### Note :

- In order to use this modified script, it might be required to enable Drive API at API console.

  - [Enable Drive API at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com/)

### References :

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.